# how to run multiple servlets in a racket web server?

Tags: racket

i read several examples showing how to deploy a servlet in a racket web server, but none mentions how to run multiple ones at a time. so, racket's web application model appeals single-servlet services?

Answer (score 3):

Each file in the `servlets` directory corresponds to a servlet. That is, all you need to do get multiple servlets is to put them in the servlets directory.
This is assuming that you are using the default configurations.

If you want more control, see:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server-internal/dispatch-servlets.html?q=servlet